# Can AvalonDock floating windows be made to not be "Always On Top"?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

Related to [my earlier question about making floating windows independent from the main DockingManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667262/can-avalon-dock-floating-anchorables-be-more-independent-from-their-parent), here's a similar, but hopefully simpler one:

**Can AvalonDock floating windows be made not to be "Always On Top" of the main DockingManager window?**

I'm rummaging around in the [AvalonDock source code](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Version2.0/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/) trying to find a way to do this, but I haven't found anything that works yet.

Ideally, I'm after something which has the same effect as Visual Studio's `Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Floating tool windows always stay on top of the main window` (available in at least VS2013 and VS2015).

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for answers to the same.

In order for a floating window to not show always on top of the docking manager, you need to remove Owner from each floating window.

dockingManager has a FloatingWindows property and you can do something like below:

```
dockingManager.FloatingWindows.ToList().ForEach(floatingWindow =>
{
    floatingWindow.Owner = null;
    floatingWindow.ShowInTaskbar = true;
});
```